# Nuget restore fails with .NET Core SDK 5.0.100

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild, nuget, .net-5

I just updated a solution to use `net50`, and it builds locally, but does not build in an Azure pipeline. How do I specify an Azure pipeline agent capable of building `net50` projects?

---

The pipeline fails on the `nuget restore` step with the following error:

```
The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error([***].csproj : error : 
Version 5.0.100 of the .NET Core SDK requires at least version 16.8.0 of MSBuild. 
The current available version of MSBuild is 16.7.0.37604. 
Change the .NET Core SDK specified in global.json to an older version that requires the MSBuild version currently available.
```

My pipeline yaml includes:

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Debug'

steps:

- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk'
  inputs:
    packageType: sdk
    version: 5.x
    installationPath: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'nuget restore'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: config
    nugetConfigPath: 'NuGet.config'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A workaround to using the `NuGetCommand@2` step is to use the `DotNetCoreCLI@2` step instead.  This may not be viable if you are building legacy (non-SDK) projects.

My YAML is now:

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Debug'

steps:

- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk'
  inputs:
    packageType: sdk
    version: 5.x
    installationPath: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet restore'
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: 'nuget.config'
```

Thanks to @Krzysztof for pointing me in the right direction.

> FWIW, and this is from memory, using `DotNetCoreCLI@2` for a `net48` project - which happened to be included in this pipeline's solution - failed under `netcoreapp3.1`, but appears to work under `net50`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks that images haven't been updated yet and 16.8 is not available. Please check this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/2022):

> We keep the visual studio version always up to date. However, deploying images can sometimes take a week(or two).